# How to create pagination using ng-repeat with angular-ui-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to implement uib-pagination , I have data in `$scope.event` based on that i want to display pagination but its not showing pagination directive itself , Any idea what is implemented wrong i do not see any error in console. Or any better approach to achieve this task ?

main.html

```
<div class="panel-body display-logs" scroll-bottom="event">
                <ul style="list-style: none;">
                    <li ng-repeat="message in event track by message.id" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message.value}}</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

    <uib-pagination total-items="event.length" ng-model='currentPage' items-per-page='pageSize' boundary-links="true">
                </uib-pagination>
```

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.event = [];
 $scope.pageSize=5,
 $scope.currentPage=1;
```

event.json

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "value": "Lorem test Ipsuver since the 1500s,but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "-19170aee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "19-9de6-19170aee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "value": "ee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
}]
```

Comment: expose your $scope.event json.

Comment: @Aravind added to question

Comment: try to set currentPage to 0. Try to define limit on repeat

Comment: oh oh. you have just 4 values then how come your pagination will work!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="panel-body display-logs" scroll-bottom="event">
  <ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="message in event | limitTo : pageSize : (currentPage - 1) * pageSize track by message.id" 
        ng-class="{lastItem: $last}">
      <strong>{{ message.id }} --- Log: </strong>
      <span>{{ message.value }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul uib-pagination 
    total-items="totalItems" 
    ng-model="currentPage" 
    items-per-page="pageSize"></ul>
```

see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YLCmEoTzhUz312X2htuB?p=preview

Comment: I see its working in plunker,  I  applied your code and i see pagination element displayed but its not working `items-per-page` is set to 5 , I do not  page 2 when we logs more than 5.

Comment: Please try to replicate it on my plunker or just create a new one with not working pagination and I will try to fix it